# Python: find top k-biggest numbers in an array

Tags: python, arrays, max

What's wrong with this code? 
Please, do not use built-in functions
Also, could you add condition for `int(k) < int(size)`

```
numbers = list()
size = input("Enter the size of an array: ")

for i in range(int(size)):
    n = input("number: ")
    numbers.append(int(n))
print(numbers)

k = input("k = ")
max = numbers[0]
top = list()

for j in range(int(k)):
    for x in numbers:
        if x > max:
            max = x
            top.append(max)
            del numbers[numbers.index(max)]
    
print(top)
```

Comment: Edit the question to explain what happens and what should happen (sample input and output, error messages if any) as properly formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the corrected version of your code:**

```
size = int(input("Enter the size of an array: ")) # Ask the user for the amount of values that will be entered
numbers = [int(input("number: ")) for _ in range(size)] # Use a list comprehension to store each input
k = int(input("k = ")) # The number of greatest values to be printed

top = list() # List to store the greatest values

for i in range(0, k): # For every unit in the number of greatest values
    max = numbers[0] # Set the maximum to any value, I chose index 0 to avoid IndexError
    for j in numbers: # For every number in the list of numbers
        if j > max: # If that number is greater than max
            max = j # Set max to that number and repeat
    top.append(max) # Add the gratest to the top list
    numbers.remove(max) # Now remove the greatest so we can proceed to find the next greatest

print(top) # Print our result!
```

**Please note that it is a bad practice to name any of your variables the names of built-in functions, so maybe change your `max` to `mx`.**

Comment: Removing elements from middle of list is pretty expensive operation, because it either shifts all elements or does additional allocation + copy. To prevent this it's possible to replace elements with `float(-inf)` instead.

Comment: note: I googled similar question because I wanted something more effective than sort+slice approach - such approach is also suggested by Ghostpunk.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have largest k numbers in the list right?
You could just sort the array and take the last k elements with a backwards iteration. Because after you sort, the largest numbers will be at the end.

The algorithm would be as follows:
0. Take the array through a for loop # You seem to have done this

1. Sort the array (Python has a native sort function, but let's just define a simple bubble sort function as you said no libraries)
2. Initialize a list or a k-tuple to hold largest numbers
3. Starting from index = array.length - 1 iterate to index = array.length - 1 - k
4. Insert each element to the k-tuple in step 2.

In Python, it would be:

```
def kLargestNumbers(array,k):
### Considering the input array is taken
    bubbleSort(array) ## if native python lib is available change it to sort()
    largest_k_numbers = list()
    for i in range(len(array)-1, len(array)-1-k,-1):
        largest_k_numbers.append(array[i])
    return largest_k_numbers

def bubbleSort(array):
    n = len(arr) 
    for i in range(n-1):  
        for j in range(0, n-i-1): 
            if arr[j] < arr[j+1] : 
               arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j], arr[j+1]
```